# SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2 Server hangs on 'Welcome' screen while connecting using RDP

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are having an issue with the SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2 servers in our environment..
While trying to log in using RDP.. the connection hangs on the 'Welcome' screen.. the server seems to be running alright and the databases can be accessed using SQL Management Studio.. but no one can log on the server.. Any thoughts??

Comment: How do you know that this is a problem with SQL Server rather than Windows itself?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? We're having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have physical access, or kvm, check the console, barring that, try mstsc /admin; if that's no go, I would try running EventViewer on another computer in the same domain and connecting it to the server, something may be getting logged that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this url [How to: View and Read SQL Server Setup Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx)  and post back any errors you might find.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried multiple users logging in over RDP, eliminating a single corrupt user profile?

As mentioned in another answer, try logging onto the actual machine as opposed to over RDP to see if you can get in that way (try it with a local admin login too).

If you can get in on the console, try removing a user profile which is having problems logging on via RDP and try it again. I've seen the logon screen hang configuring Internet Explorer before (I'd just rebooted after installing IE8) and deleting the affected user profile folder did the trick.